# MySQL Query and then Update

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to query the table in MySQL. I want to get the whole raw and then update the TF column of it.

It looks like this:

```
UPDATE database1.DOC_INFO SET TF='1'

WHERE  (
          
          SELECT * FROM DOC_INFO WHERE SPECIALTY='Internal Medicine' AND
          LOCATION='NYC' AND TF like 0 LIMIT 1
);
```

I get error code 1241. Operand should contain 1 column. How can I change it so it works?

Comment: you sub query doesn't make sense, how should mysql know which row to update with that SELECT query. if you have an ID field SELECT that and use it in the where clause4

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is very simple. A simple update query would work just fine as you are trying to select and update the same table. It should look something like this.

```
UPDATE 
database1.DOC_INFO 
SET 
TF='1' 
WHERE 
SPECIALTY='Internal Medicine' 
AND LOCATION ='NYC'
AND TF = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked but I also want to output the whole raw that's why I had SELECT used, how can I include it?

Comment: If you want to only `SELECT` those rows that are getting changed, you can't do the `UPDATE` and `SELECT` in a single statement. What I would do is select the list of rows to be updated into a TMP table (just the primary key is enough), then do the `UPDATE` and `SELECT` by joining on the TMP table. Or you could add a flag column called something like `just_updated`, set this flag in the UPDATE, then SELECT the rows with this flag, then run another UPDATE to clear the flag. But both methods are subject to race conditions, if the procedure is run twice a the exact same time.